# What's the best way of finding the highest value of a table, that is inside a table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

The title is somewhat self-explanatory. I have a table containing a lot of smaller tables with two integers. I need to find the highest/lowest value of the first and second integer within those sub-tables and then output the entire sub-table with the highest/lowest number.

The only way I can come up with seems fairly unintuitive and expensive.

Answer (score 2):

If you need Lua to do the work for you, you can use `table.sort` and pass it your own sorting function that will sort based on the values of first/second integer and then pick first/last element from the sorted table. If you can maintain the sorted order when inserting (using binary search for a position), then you can always pick the first/last element as needed.